# Possibilites for Sharkovskii's theorem.

Tags: dynamical-systems

Hello I am interested in Sharkovskii's theorem with respect to two aspects:

- Possibilities of generalization for other spaces with some additional structures or dimensions.

  - Applications in dynamical systems, other branches of mathematics and real life(!?)

Some references are appreciated.

Comment: Could you please be a bit more specific as to what generalizations you are looking for? As to the applications, Sharkovskii's theorem is a result on periodicity of dynamical systems.

Comment: I would recommend you read the paper "Period Three Implies Chaos" by Tien-Yien Li & James A. Yorke

Comment: Just try Googling [Sharkovskii theorem](https://www.google.com/search?q=sharkovskii+theorem&client=firefox-b&ei=YvVSW_XlIOar6ATXupDADQ&start=20&sa=N&biw=1440&bih=735).

Comment: Almost the same question was posted in MO [References and background on Sharkovskii's theorem](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/306503/references-and-background-on-sharkovskiis-theorem). I think that simultaneous cross-posting, without mentioning it, is considered a bad practice

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just quickly, it is not true in the circle. It has been shown in the context of unique beta expansions. See N. Sidorov et al paper Periodic unique beta-expansions: the Sharkovskiĭ ordering. Perhaps, it might hold on some one-dimensional spaces like finite graphs without circles or hereditarly indecomposable continua such as the pseudoarc. Seems difficult to hold for higher dimensional spaces in my opinion.

As for applications a quick one is related to the structure of some limit spaces of tent maps. Check W. Ingram's work.